# How to cascade dependency resolution w/ CDI (WELD)

Tags: inversion-of-control, cdi, jboss-weld

I would like to have a central weld container that holds all my services and so on. This container would however be wrapped by a second container which contains local settings. The goal is if a dependency cannot be found in the outer container then I would like to then search the inner container.

How can I achieve this? I would prefer to do things in a standlike manner, without reverting to use of non standard WELD extensions.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but couldn't you simply have one jar with your services, and a "configuration" jar with produces methods, that the service jar plugs into? Then you could swap your configuration jars for whatever you need at build time. Haven't tried this, just speculation.

Comment: That prolly wouldnt work in a dynamic environment like OSGI. Weld seems very static and not very configurable programmatically, its all annotations which are baked in at compile time from what i can tell.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this. There is one `BeanManager`, which resolves dependencies by looking if any if its `Context`s (related to scopes) contains the desired dependency.

Comment: BeanManager is not really a standard javax.inject class but rather a WELD implementation class. I suppose its an answer but then again using internal classses is never good. This is disappointing as i thoight the who;e point of CDI was standardization...

Comment: I meant this is the way how CDI is supposed to function (based on the SPI). You aren't supposed to use SPI interfaces.

Comment: Yes and tahts the shortfall. Its very static and does not offer a "dynamic" way.